# Make an optional property required when another property is present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have proptypes shown below

```
interface Props {
  resource: string;
  create?: boolean;
  route?: string;
}
```

As can be seen above, create and route are optional props. However, I would like to implement the types such that if create prop is present then route must now be required. Anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should group these props and make that grouped prop optional as

```
interface RouteProps {
  create: boolean;
  route: string;
}

interface Props {
  resource: string;
  routeInfo?: RouteProps;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can split it into a union of two types and use `create` with a literal type:

```
type Props = {
  resource: string;
  create?: false;
  route?: string
} | {
  resource: string;
  create: true;
  route: string;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

although I like @DevLoverUmar 's solution more. You actually have the option to do something like this with typescript:

this might be what you re looking for. But you would have to explicitly set `TArgs<true>`

```
type TArgs<T extends boolean> = {
   a: T,
   b: string,
   c: T extends true ? string : null
 }
```

Example of how it could look with a factory function:

```
type TArgs<T extends true | false> = {
    a: T,
    c?: T extends true ? string : null
}

const argsFactory = <T extends boolean>(a: T, c: T extends true ? string : null): TArgs<T> => {
    return {
        a,
        c
    }
}

// Works
argsFactory(true, "string");
argsFactory(false, null);

// Doesnt Work
argsFactory(false, "some String");
argsFactory(true, null)
```