# How to make a type optional if other exists?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create and interface for a component props. Currently it looks like this:

```
interface IContextMenuProps {
  text: string;
  image: string;
}
```

I want the text to be optional if image is provided and viceversa. On other words, one of them has to exist.

Comment: You can do this as a union of two types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using a discriminated union: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript - make an optional property required when another property is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64649356/typescript-make-an-optional-property-required-when-another-property-is-present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you need to use union.

Type will be something like this:

```
type IContextMenuProps = ({ text: string } | { image: string });
```

Answer (score -1):

you can optional text key, something like.

```
type IContextMenuProps = ({ text: string } | { image: string });
```