# Can a TypeScript interface property be defined as required based on the value of another property within the same interface?

Tags: typescript

The customSymbol property should become required if operator is 'CUSTOM_CHAR_LEFT' or 'CUSTOM_CHAR_RIGHT'

```
export type PadOperator =
  | 'CUSTOM_CHAR_LEFT'
  | 'CUSTOM_CHAR_RIGHT'
  | 'NONE'
  | 'SPACE_CHAR_LEFT'
  | 'SPACE_CHAR_RIGHT'
  | 'ZERO_CHAR_LEFT'
  | 'ZERO_CHAR_RIGHT'
  ;
  
interface PadOption {
    operator: PadOperator;
    customSymbol: string
}
```

I tried the following without success:

```
interface PadOption {
    operator: PadOperator;
    customSymbol: PadOperator extends ('CUSTOM_CHAR_LEFT' | 'CUSTOM_CHAR_RIGHT') ? string | undefined;
}
```

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but for this example why not put: customSymbol?: PadOperator...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript - make an optional property required when another property is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64649356/typescript-make-an-optional-property-required-when-another-property-is-present)

Comment: @SteveTomlin because the consumer could forget to pass the customSymbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use a type alias instead of an interface, then read on. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) for an explanation of why they can usually be used interchangeably.

Using a type alias, you can constraint the type using a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and pick the excluded values using [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers).

```
type PadOption = {
  operator: "CUSTOM_CHAR_LEFT" | "CUSTOM_CHAR_RIGHT";
  customSymbol: string;
} | {
  operator: Exclude<PadOperator, "CUSTOM_CHAR_LEFT" | "CUSTOM_CHAR_RIGHT">
  customSymbol?: string;
};
```

See Typescript playground example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsFNQYwK4GcAuB7AtgZQJ4YEZoA2oADgE5qnTko6hKRoJEAmo+0cms50AjggCWfdkIBmoKjQCG6cqCFJQAcgDCAVSzgA8gFkA+moASAQQBKBgDIBRAGLgVUheq27DJiwfMBJAOLGjgBQ0AAepGi0oHTUoAAKMqw61ORykaAAvEGgoAA+qpra+kZmlrYOKtl5BW7Fnpa+AcE5+SoAcjptNpUtqlhxpmo2JV7lzdUq-YPD9d7+gT0TAFo25jojZfbjrStrG3NNiwDcQUExsAlJpChCaAB2maAA3lXSqfIAXKAARIXu+2NvtVfrUPKUDoFviccohUJhcARiF9UOQhHcAOYnAC+1ReOTeaXIXxsoTgRAQrGgAB5LslZPIADQ-P51cGA4EssFeRqQgB8VVh6GweEIRAA-MiUKiMdiTkEiNAUKBKeIZCwUMkbvcvrTrrcHhlnlV8SlCV9vh0ut8gljTgqlYLMJr9T47gA3GREISsHWJZ33R54nJSU2fZmggFba22+WK+DIIX+u6+q5ag1G4Mh+mRc2cyMOb4M43xuHCxFEc3iNBoQs2oA).

Comment: This is a great answer, however I believe the user requested an interface and not a type alias.

I'd suggest making a quick mention on how you can then extend 'PadOption' with an interface.

Comment: thanks, i edited my answer to explain that

Comment: I can live with type alias, works great thank you